# Zoom Image using WPF MVVM, will move the top layer controls. How can it be fixed on image zoom time?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently i am working on image processing project, where i have one review screen in which i set the image on image container, and on top of the image, all four corners has meta data, which are fixed. Means while i zoom in/out the image, the top content will remain at the fixed position not move. This is my requirement.

Now i have set all content dynamically using the stack panel and all meta data will stay on fixed position except the bottom right position, which will be moved while image is zoomed in/out.

below is the reference screen shot where red mark shows the metadata will moved and hide at right side.

[image: Image container]

Here is the code for bottom right content

```
public async Task<ScrollViewer> CreateNewScrollViewer(ImageInfo item)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewerObj = new ScrollViewer();

        byte[] rawData;
        try
        {

            //this will update the values of any older sharpness data to 5
            if (item.AnnotationSchemaVersion != null && item.AnnotationSchemaVersion.Equals("1.0", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                item.AdjustmentValue.Sharpness = item.BytePerPixel == 3 ? _samSettingsManager.GetTrueColorSharpnessDefaultValue() : _samSettingsManager.GetSingleColorSharpnessDefaultValue();
                var saveSharpness = new Task(() => this.UpdateImageAnalysis(item));
                saveSharpness.Start();
            }


            scrollViewerObj.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_ScrollViewer");
            scrollViewerObj.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_ScrollViewer");

            scrollViewerObj.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
            scrollViewerObj.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
            scrollViewerObj.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
            scrollViewerObj.Focusable = true;
            scrollViewerObj.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(ScrollViewerSizeChanged);

            Point? fixationTarget = null;
            Point? foveaXY = null;
            Point? onhXY = null;
            FixationType fixationMode = FixationType.Internal;
            bool performDistortionCorrection = false;
            // Provide fixation values only for WF and Non-External(Non-AnteriorSegment) scans, as distortion correction shall only be applied to WF and Non-External(Non-AnteriorSegment) images.
            // All composite UWF/Montage/Auto-Montage images will be distortion corrected (Montage algorithm generates distortion corrected image)
            if (Convert.ToInt32(item.FOV, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == FOVConstants.Widefield &&
                item.ExamMode != ExamModes.AnteriorSegment && SAMConstants.SAMExamSourceUID == item.ExamSourceUID)
            {
                fixationTarget = item.FixationXY;
                foveaXY = item.FoveaXY;
                onhXY = item.ONHXY;
                fixationMode = item.FixationMode;
                performDistortionCorrection = true;
            }
            //bool isOD = item.Laterality == "OD" ? true : false;


            string imageCacheFilePath = _imageCacheFilePath;
            string imageFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.ImagePath);


            //creates the image cache folder if it doesn't exist
            if (!Directory.Exists(imageCacheFilePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imageCacheFilePath);

            ImageContainer imageObj = new ImageContainer(_pixelBufferSize);

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                imageObj.Initialize(item.ImagePath, item.ImageCompressionType,
```

item.ImageWidth, item.ImageHeight, item.BytePerPixel, item.ExamSourceUID, item.Laterality, imageCacheFilePath, _pixelBufferSize, fixationTarget,
foveaXY, item.ProjectedXMin, item.ProjectedYMax, item.ProjectedXMax, item.ProjectedYMin, performDistortionCorrection,
onhXY, fixationMode, item.ONHIdentificationMode);

```
            });


            imageObj.InitializeZoomValues(((int)ActualHeight - 40) / 4, ((int)ActualWidth - 40) / 4);

            PyramidTools.PyramidImageProcessing processImage = new PyramidTools.PyramidImageProcessing();

            //Sets up the pyramid 
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(imageCacheFilePath + imageFileName + ExtensionConstants.Raw) || (!System.IO.File.Exists(imageCacheFilePath + imageFileName + ExtensionConstants.Text) && SAMConstants.SAMExamSourceUID == imageObj.ExamSourceUID))
            {
                rawData = imageObj.ImageDataObj.GetData();
                if (rawData != null)
                {
                    processImage.CreatePyramidForGivenImage(rawData, item.BytePerPixel, (int)imageObj.ImageZoom.LowestZoomPercentage, imageFileName, imageObj.ImageDataObj.Width, imageObj.ImageDataObj.Height, imageCacheFilePath);
                }
            }
            else if (!processImage.IsPyramidCreated(imageCacheFilePath + imageFileName, (int)imageObj.ImageZoom.LowestZoomPercentage))
            {
                rawData = File.ReadAllBytes(imageCacheFilePath + imageFileName + ExtensionConstants.Raw);
                if (rawData != null)
                {
                    processImage.CreatePyramidForGivenImage(rawData, item.BytePerPixel, (int)imageObj.ImageZoom.LowestZoomPercentage, imageFileName, imageObj.ImageDataObj.Width, imageObj.ImageDataObj.Height, imageCacheFilePath);
                }
            }

            //  For image sharpness
            imageObj.ImageProcessing = imageProcessing;
            imageObj.TrueColorSharpnessRadius = _trueColorSharpnessRadius;
            imageObj.TrueColorSharpnessMinAmount = _trueColorSharpnessMinAmount;
            imageObj.TrueColorSharpnessMaxAmount = _trueColorSharpnessMaxAmount;
            imageObj.TrueColorSharpnessResizeFactor = _trueColorSharpnessResizeFactor;
            imageObj.SingleColorSharpnessRadius = _singleColorSharpnessRadius;
            imageObj.SingleColorSharpnessMinAmount = _singleColorSharpnessMinAmount;
            imageObj.SingleColorSharpnessMaxAmount = _singleColorSharpnessMaxAmount;
            imageObj.SingleColorSharpnessResizeFactor = _singleColorSharpnessResizeFactor;
            imageObj.TrueColorSharpnessFactor = _trueColorSharpnessFactor;
            imageObj.SingleColorSharpnessFactor = _singleColorSharpnessFactor;

            imageObj.IsConstituteImage = item.IsConstituteImage;

            imageObj.FOV = item.FOV;
            imageObj.SelectedChannel = ChannelTypes.TrueColorChannel;
            imageObj.TonalOptimizedValues = new Tonal(128, 128, 128);
            imageObj.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_ImageContainer");
            imageObj.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_ImageContainer");

            BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
            logo.BeginInit();
            logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SAMProduction.FundusImageDisplay;component/Images/RotateBlue.png");
            logo.EndInit();

            imageObj.ImageRotationShow = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.Source = logo;
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_180DegreeIcon");
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_180DegreeIcon");
            //imageObj.ImageRotationShow.SetResourceReference(Canvas.BackgroundProperty, "180DegreeIcon");
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.Width = 30;
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.Height = 30;
            imageObj.ImageRotationShow.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

            imageObj.ImageFrameNoMessage = item.ImageFrameNoMessage;
            Style textBlockStyle = this.TryFindResource("TextWhite16") as Style;

            #region Top Left Panel Information
            StackPanel topLeftPanelInfo = new StackPanel();
            topLeftPanelInfo.Width = 160;
            topLeftPanelInfo.Name = "TopLeftPanel";
            topLeftPanelInfo.Uid = "TopLeftPanel";
            topLeftPanelInfo.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            topLeftPanelInfo.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            topLeftPanelInfo.Margin = new Thickness(10, 5, 0, 0);

            UpdateTopLeftPanel(item, imageObj, topLeftPanelInfo, textBlockStyle);
            #endregion

            #region Bottom Left Panel Information
            StackPanel bottomLeftPanelInfo = new StackPanel();
            bottomLeftPanelInfo.Name = "BottomLeftPanel";
            bottomLeftPanelInfo.Uid = "BottomLeftPanel";
            bottomLeftPanelInfo.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            bottomLeftPanelInfo.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            bottomLeftPanelInfo.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 5);

            UpdateBottomLeftPanel(item, imageObj, bottomLeftPanelInfo, textBlockStyle);
            #endregion

            #region Bottom Right Panel Information
            StackPanel bottomRightPanelInfo = new StackPanel();
            bottomRightPanelInfo.Name = "BottomRightPanel";
            bottomRightPanelInfo.Uid = "BottomRightPanel";
            bottomRightPanelInfo.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_BottomRightPanelInfo");
            bottomRightPanelInfo.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_BottomRightPanelInfo");
            bottomRightPanelInfo.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            bottomRightPanelInfo.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            bottomRightPanelInfo.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 5);

            UpdateBottomRightPanel(item, imageObj, bottomRightPanelInfo, textBlockStyle);
            #endregion

            #region Top Right Panel Information
            StackPanel topRightPanelInfo = new StackPanel();
            topRightPanelInfo.Name = "TopRightPanel";
            topRightPanelInfo.Uid = "TopRightPanel";
            topRightPanelInfo.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_TopRightPanelInfo");
            topRightPanelInfo.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_TopRightPanelInfo");
            topRightPanelInfo.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            topRightPanelInfo.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            topRightPanelInfo.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 10, 0);

            UpdateTopRightPanel(item, imageObj, topRightPanelInfo, textBlockStyle);
            #endregion

            Grid gridObj = new Grid() { ClipToBounds = true };//

            gridObj.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_Grid");
            gridObj.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "ReviewImageDetailView_Grid");

            gridObj.Children.Add(imageObj);

            if (topLeftPanelInfo != null)
            {
                gridObj.Children.Add(topLeftPanelInfo);
            }
            if (bottomLeftPanelInfo != null)
            {
                gridObj.Children.Add(bottomLeftPanelInfo);
            }
            if (topRightPanelInfo != null)
            {
                gridObj.Children.Add(topRightPanelInfo);
            }
            if (bottomRightPanelInfo != null)
            {
                gridObj.Children.Add(bottomRightPanelInfo);
            }

            gridObj.Children.Add(imageObj.SelectedBorder);
            gridObj.Children.Add(imageObj.ImageRotationShow);
            gridObj.Children.Add(imageObj.OverlayGrid);

            imageObj.OverlayGrid.MouseLeftButtonUp += OverlayGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            imageObj.OverlayGrid.MouseMove += OverlayGrid_MouseMove;
            imageObj.OverlayGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown += OverlayGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            imageObj.OverlayGrid.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += OverlayGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown;
            imageObj.OverlayGrid.PreviewMouseRightButtonUp += OverlayGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp;

            scrollViewerObj.Content = gridObj;

            // This binding required to align image properly when it is loading.
            Binding HeightBinding = new Binding();
            RelativeSource relativeheightSource = new RelativeSource();
            relativeheightSource.Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor;
            relativeheightSource.AncestorType = typeof(ScrollViewer);
            HeightBinding.RelativeSource = relativeheightSource;
            HeightBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight");
            HeightBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            HeightBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            imageObj.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.HeightProperty, HeightBinding);

            Binding WidthBinding = new Binding();
            RelativeSource relativeWidthSource = new RelativeSource();
            relativeWidthSource.Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor;
            relativeWidthSource.AncestorType = typeof(ScrollViewer);
            WidthBinding.RelativeSource = relativeWidthSource;
            WidthBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth");
            WidthBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            WidthBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            imageObj.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.WidthProperty, WidthBinding);

            imageObj.ImageSourceChanged += this.ImageObj_ImageSourceChanged;

            imageObj.ZoomValueChanged += this.ImageObj_ZoomValueChanged;

            scrollViewerObj.AllowDrop = true;
            scrollViewerObj.Drop += ScrollViewer_Drop;

            imageObj.ContainerTonalValueChanged += ImageObj_ContainerTonalValueChanged;

            // Previously MouseLeftButtonDown event was used. 
            // Change set no 141851 has change code of CreateNewScrollViewer(). He set Scrollviewer’s Focable property to true.
            // It is required to set focusable true for that change set.
            // In ScrollViewer's original code (.net code) it is handling event (e.Handled = true) if it can get focus.
            // So side effect of 141851 change set is MouseLeftButtonDown event of scrollviewer do not get call when mouse down on it.
            // So it misbehaves.
            // So here PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event used.

            scrollViewerObj.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += ScrollViewerObj_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            scrollViewerObj.MouseLeftButtonUp += this.ScrollViewerObj_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            scrollViewerObj.PreviewMouseWheel += ScrollViewerObj_PreviewMouseWheel;

            // No need to handle this event
            //imageObj.SizeChanged += this.ImageObj_SizeChanged;
            imageObj.MouseMove += this.ImageObj_MouseMove;
            imageObj.MouseLeftButtonDown += this.ImageObj_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            imageObj.MouseLeftButtonUp += this.ImageObj_MouseLeftButtonUp;

            gridObj.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            gridObj.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

            //It is not necessary to initalize the data
            imageObj.ImageID = item.ImageId;
            //imageObj.ImagePath = item.ImagePath;

            if (imageObj.ExamSourceUID == SAMConstants.SAMExamSourceUID &&
                imageObj.ExamMode != ExamModes.AnteriorSegment)
                imageObj.OverlayGrid.IsHitTestVisible = IsOverlayGridEnable;
            else
                imageObj.OverlayGrid.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            // imageObj.OverlayGrid.IsHitTestVisible = IsOverlayGridEnable;
            //imageObj.ImageSource = imageObj.ImageDataObj;

            scrollViewerObj.ContextMenu = CreateContextMenu(scrollViewerObj, imageObj); // set contextmenu
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _services.Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "SAMProduction.FundusImageDisplay", "ImageEditViewerBase", "CreateNewScrollViewer: Error occurred while creating new scrollviewer. : " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            rawData = null;
        }
        return scrollViewerObj;
    }
```

Please, let me help out to resolve the moved content on top layer of image, if any one can do. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find creating views in code very unreadable, so this is how to achieve this in XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Image .../> // or whatever custom control you use to allow zoom

  <StackPanel Name="TopLeft HorizontalAligment="Left" VerticalAligment="Top">
       <contente: labels etc ../>
  </StackPanel>

  ...
  <StackPanel Name="BottomRight" HorizontalAligment="Right" VerticalAligment="Bottom">
       <contente: labels etc ../>
  </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The trick is to wrap everything that you want to be in the same place and/or overlay in a Grid. If the StackPanels are after an Image in Grid content, their z-index will be higher and they will be displayed on top of the image.

The Image control by default will be streched to the whole grid, so you should manipulate the zoom with its content, not its size. If that's problematic, just wrap the Image control with another panel, or at best, custom UserControl and work out the size issues there.

Thanks to the Grid, the StackPanels will anchored to the corners, no matter the size and shape of the grid.

Also, you used tag MVVM and your code is almost textbook non-MVVM.

Maybe this will help you rewrite your code.